# Looping, copy a list of files from one destination to the next VBA

Tags: vba

The following macro I am trying to use to move files in one location to another from an excel spreadsheet. The copy and pastes are used to copy the formula driven "source location" and "destination location" to new columns, to be used in the macro.

I keep getting the error? What is not right right with my approach?

```
Sub Combine()
    Paste_Values
    Paste_Values_Two
    Copy_Files
End Sub

Sub Paste_Values()
    Range("C2:C1000").Copy
    Range("E2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub

Sub Paste_Values_Two()
    Range("D2:D1000").Copy
    Range("F2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub

Sub Copy_Files()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("E2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        FileCopy Source:=cell.Value, Destination:=cell.Offset(, 1).Value
    Next cell

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "NOT WORKING"
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is completely unreadable.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hi @Harvey. I get the "NOT WORKING" message. I am trying to try AGolds suggestion below but not having any luck. Just to add my source path is in the format: Z:\1. Pro\XYZ\08\6. D\Mel.docx. My destination path is in the format: Z:\1. Pro\XYZ\08_Decision_Tracker\5. M\1006\Mel.docx

Comment: Okay, have you stepped though your code to see which line jumps to your error handler?

Comment: No I am not sure how to determine that. I probably should add I am still a newb with this. I have my code open in developer. I have selected step into and it goes straight to highlighting the "Sub Combine" line?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my comment, you can remove (or comment) the `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` line and you'll get a more precise error, but I think the only thing that can go wrong are the `FileCopy` or maybe something in the range. (See my updated answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any information at the error handling you do not know what exactly happens. However the only function which seems to be able to give an error is [`FileCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264390.aspx):

> If you try to use the FileCopy statement on a currently open file, an error occurs.

To show the error you can:

1. Disable the error handling (`On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`). This gave me the error: "Run-time error '53': File not found", but is not really user friendly since it stops the script.
2. You probably want something more informative, and handle this situation (by giving a message, and continuing to the following item). A more informative error message can be:

   ```
   Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
     MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
   ```

You might want to change the error handling to:

```
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
      MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Resume Next
```

With `Resume Next` the `For Each` loop is continued.

**Edit 1**: If you get the error, are you sure that your files exist? You mentioned in your comments you have files like: `Z:\1. Pro\XYZ\08_Decision_Tracker\5. M\1006\Mel.docx`, are you completely sure the path is correct, do all the (sub)directories exist? And do you have write permission to `Z:`?